# Get window url inside JSON

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, aem

Is there any way to get the window's url inside Json. I tried below but doesn't working.
JSON is used to display the widget. Below is the snippet of code.

```
CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.getResultsBoxConfig({
            "itemsDDGroups": [CQ.wcm.EditBase.DD_GROUP_ASSET],
            "itemsDDNewParagraph": {
                "path": "foundation/components/image",
                "propertyName": "./fileReference"
            },
            "noRefreshButton": true,
            "tbar": [
                CQ.wcm.ContentFinderTab.REFRESH_BUTTON,
                "->",
             {

            "url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json"+window.location.href;
        }, {
            "baseParams": {
                /*"defaultMimeType": "image"*/
                "mimeType": "image"
            },
            "autoLoad":false,
            "reader": new CQ.Ext.data.JsonReader({
                "totalProperty": "results",
                "root": "hits",
                "fields": [
                    "name", "path", "title", "mimeType", "ddGroups", "size", "lastModified", "ck", "templateParams", "imageWidth", "imageHeight"
                ],
                "id": "path"
            })
        })
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? Adding the url to the file itself?

Comment: What does "inside JSON" mean - show more code

Comment: Actually this is the callback, want to hit the servlet with window url as request param.

Comment: When you mean window's url, do you want only the path of the content or the entire url. I meant `/content/xyz/something.html` or `http://somedomain.com/cf#/content/xyz/something.html` ?

Comment: I need only /content/xyz/something.html or no issues if i get full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JSON here. Just an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals)

You need to remove the trailing semicolon from the object you send and perhaps add a parameter name. I would also encode the URL

```
{"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json?url="+
  encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)
},
```

If you only need the hash, you do not need the parameter name nor the encode

```
{"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json"+ location.hash},
```

If there is more stuff in the hash than you want, you need to split it

```
{"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json"+ 
 location.hash.split(".html")[0]+".html"
},
```

or to be sure:

```
{"url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json"+ 
 (location.hash.indexOf(".html")!=-1?location.hash.split(".html")[0]+".html":location.hash)
},
```

Comment: Ok, i have remove semicolon, but still its not working. My page source showing "url": "/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json"+window.location.href rather than the value of window.location.href

Comment: What page source? getResultsBoxConfig needs to get the URL and do something with it.

Comment: Hi encodeURIComponent(window.location.hash) seems solved the problem its giving me below result localhost:4502/bin/wcm/contentfinder/asset/viewnew.json%23%2Fcontent%2FCompany%2Fen%2FArticle.html?_dc=1403269699278&query=&mimeType=image&_ but I dont want in encoded   format. just looking for content/Company/en/Article.html.

Comment: So use the second version WITHOUT the encoding